# How to fix redirection problems in a react-material menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

With my menu I encounter different problem.

For **starters**, in the first RETURN, I have a TREEITEM with a LISTITEM and a LISTITETEXT.

I put an OnClick in the LISTITETEXT so that if the id of my menu is equal to a value I authorize a redirection.

However, the redirection reloads the page and this is not the purpose of my menu when I use react.

**Second**, I have my other RETURN which contains my submenu.

it is displayed correctly, when I click on the TREEITEM, I am redirected to the right page.

However, I have the error in the console:

> Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on:
>   "/extranetV1/prospect"

```
{stoMenu && (
                <TreeView
                  style={layout.menu}
                  defaultCollapseIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon />}
                  defaultExpandIcon={<ArrowRightIcon />}
                >
                  {stoMenu.root.children.map(menu => {
                    return (
                      <TreeItem
                        key={menu.nodeId}
                        nodeId={menu.nodeId}
                        label={
                          <ListItem style={layout.menuListItem} className={menu.iconCls}>
                            <ListItemText style={layout.menuText} primary={menu.text} onClick={() => {
                              if (menu.id === '/accueil') {
                                window.location.assign(menu.id);
                              }
                            }} />
                          </ListItem>
                        }
                      >
                        {menu.children.map(child => {
                          return (
                            <TreeItem
                              key={child.nodeId}
                              nodeId={child.nodeId}
                              label={child.text}
                            >
                                  <Redirect to={child.id}/>
                            </TreeItem>
                          );
                        })}
                      </TreeItem>
                    );
                  })}
                </TreeView>
              )}
```

Comment: I solved my problem thank you

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted if that helped you :)

Answer (score 5):

For both scenarios you use redirection in react wrong.

You need to use [react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) for redirection inside react app and instead of `window.location.assign(menu.id)` it will be `props.history.push(menu.id)`.

I see in the second one you use [Redirect](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md) component. The problem is that you trigger redirect each time in the loop. You should set some state instead and trigger render with condition earlier in the code.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ pathToRedirect: null });

  const handleRedirect = (to) => {
    setState({ pathToRedirect: to});
  }

  render () {
     if (state.pathToRedirect) {
       return <Redirect to={state.pathToRedirect} />;
     }
     //render list with handleRedirect onClick
     return (...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To correct my problem of reloading the page, I integrated this:

```
                      <TreeItem
                        key={menu.nodeId}
                        nodeId={menu.nodeId}
                        label={
                          <ListItem style={layout.menuListItem} className={menu.iconCls}>
                            <ListItemText style={layout.menuText} primary={menu.text} onClick={() => {
                              if (menu.id === '/accueil') {
                                this.props.history.push(menu.id);
                              }
                            }} />
                          </ListItem>
                        }
                      >
```

I removed the REDIRECT by this in my sub menu :

```
                           <TreeItem
                              key={child.nodeId}
                              nodeId={child.nodeId}
                              label={child.text}
                              onClick={() => {
                                if (child.id) {
                                  this.props.history.push(child.id);
                                }
                              }}
                            />
```